# Install NupenGL offline in VS2017?

Tags: opengl, nuget, visual-studio-2017

Trying to install [this specific NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nupengl.core/) in an *offline* VS2017 environment.

However, despite downloading the .nupkg file and saving it in the specified offline NuGet package directory under "NuGet Package Manager Settings", the package does not appear in the list in the NuGet package manager in VS2017.

Do I need to unzip the file first? Have tried that but receive the error that the .nupkg file does not contain a .nuspec file (despite clearly containing one in File Explorer).

**Could someone with VS2017 try to install this specific NuGet package in an offline VS2017 environment and provide a clearly worded, unambiguous step-by-step guide on how to install the package?**

Comment: What is an "offline VS2017 environment", exactly?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 without an internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could someone with VS2017 try to install this specific NuGet package in an offline VS2017 environment and provide a clearly worded, unambiguous step-by-step guide on how to install the package?

To accomplish install nuget package in an offline VS2017 environment, please following below steps:

1. Manually download that nuget package, save it to your local location, for example, `D:\Test\NuGet`. You will get a file ending in `.nupakg`: `nupengl.core.0.1.0.1.nupkg`.
2. Open a command prompt with administrator from start menu, switch the path to where nuget.exe exists, for example, `C:\Users\Admin`. Then add the download package to the ffline NuGet package directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages` by below command:

   ```
   nuget add "D:\Test\NuGet\nupengl.core.0.1.0.1.nupkg" -source "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages"
   ```

   [image]

   After that, you will find the nuget package be added to the the offline NuGet package directory with a hierarchical layout:

   [image]
3. Then you can use this nuget package when your Visual Studio 2017 without an internet connection:

   [image]

Comment: Really appreciate this guide! This has explained a lot more to me than just the original question. Very helpful answer!

Comment: I mean, it didn't work that way for me, and now everyone knows what I'm doing all the time (logged my ip again?) but your guide is clearly worded and concise.

Comment: Reinstalled VS2017 and am now getting this error when following your guide: 'System.AggregateException' Error when using the Package Console to install the Nuget Package. 'The remote name could not be resolved api.nuget.org'.

Comment: When you install that package from Package Console, you should specify the nuget source with this command: `Install-package nupengl.core -source "Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages"`. Do not forget double quotes.

Comment: The problem persists. I've created a custom offline install directory using Packet Manager Settings but am still receiving the above error.

Comment: The problem has been solved! It turns out the VS 2017 NuGet Manager automatically checks for packages at the NuGet website FIRST, before any other sources. If it doesn't find them there it returns the above error. You need to uncheck the 'Api.Nuget.org' package source in the Tools > Package Manager Sources menu.